# Arithmetic Exception integer

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

when i try to input this integer i get an error
   -10 20 -40 << error
   the output should be 80

```
{ 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
String[] input = new String[n]; 
  for (String input1 : input) {
      input = in.readLine().split(" ");
      int x = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
      int y = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
      int z = Integer.parseInt(input[2]); 
      if (y - x == z - y)
      {
          System.out.println(z+ y - x);
      }
      else
      {  //-10 20 -40
          System.out.println(z / (x / y));
      }
```

Comment: Your code does not work, have you tried running it?

Comment: `in.readLine()` - where does `in` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`z / (x / y)` results in  division by zero.

Why?

Because `x / y` == `-10 / 20` == 0.

Why?

`x` and `y` are `int`s so the `/` in `x / y` means integer division. In integer division, 20 goes into -10 zero times, with a remainder of -10.  The remainder is discarded and the result is the quotient of zero.

The solution: force `(x / y)` to be evaluated in `double` arithmetic by casting either `x` or `y` to `double`:

```
z / ((double)x / y)   
z / (x / (double)y)
```

Now, because `(x / y)` is a `double`, `z / (x / y)` is also evaluated in `double` math.  And in `double` math, `x / y` == `-0.5`, `-40 / -0.5` == `80`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `double` instead of `int` since it only can store whole numbers. `-10/20` becomes `-0.5` but is converted to `0`. Here is what you can do:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    String[] input = new String[3];
    for (String input1 : input) {
        input = "-10 20 -40".split(" ");
        double x = Double.parseDouble(input[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(input[1]);
        double z = Double.parseDouble(input[2]);
        if (y - x == z - y) {
            System.out.println(z + y - x);
        } else {  //-10 20 -40
            System.out.println(z / (x / y));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
80.0
```